# Count distinct words from a dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I tried to split words then count them by using python pandas.

The original data is like,

```
col_A 

happy, not happy
sad,happy
sad, happy
angry, happy
angry, sad
```

I tried using this function to count the words in col_A.

```
word_list= df.col_A.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(","))).sum(axis=0)

word_list.sort_values(ascending = False)
```

It will give me the results like,

```
angry       2
happy       2
sad         2
 happy      2
 not happy  1
 sad        1
```

How can I avoid these blanks to return the real counts of values?

I want to return a list like,

```
happy      4
sad        3
angry      2
not happy  1
```

Comment: is there always a two value column? i.e. of the form `value1, value2`

Comment: Did you try `x.split(",").trim()` or `x.split(",").strip()to remove extra white spaces?

Comment: @Yuca No, some rows will give you 3 or 4 values. Not always 2. Actually, 3 values are most frequently.

Comment: just use `.str.strip()` on your series and you should have what you want

Comment: @Yuca I tried this, `df.col_A.str.strip().apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(","))).sum(axis=0)`, but the results didn't change..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liner, can't vouch for efficiency but it works :)

```
pd.Series([x.strip() for x in df.col_A.str.split(',').sum()]).value_counts()
```

### Output:

```
happy        4
sad          3
angry        2
not happy    1
```

### Efficiency Test:

```
%timeit pd.Series([x.strip() for x in df.col_A.str.split(',').sum()]).value_counts()
1.19 ms ± 35.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series(sum([list(map(str.strip, i.split(','))) for i in df['col_A']], [])).value_counts()
1.13 ms ± 20.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Actually, pandas .str accessor method are really slow.  List comprehension almost always outperforms using .str in pandas. +1

Comment: honest question, then what's the bottleneck? the `df.col_A.str.split()`?

Comment: Yes, str.split.  You could instead use list comprehension and python string method split and it would be faster. I think.

Comment: Newbie question, are you guys talking about the difference between `df.col` and `df['col']`?

Comment: @JiayuZhang to the best of my understanding, no :)

Comment: @ScottBoston can you share some light on your suggestion? I'm trying to follow it but i'm failing so far

Comment: `pd.Series(sum([list(map(str.strip, i.split(','))) for i in df['col_A']], [])).value_counts()` one way.

Comment: Using python string methods and list comprehension vs using .str accessor and pandas methods.

Comment: @ScottBoston updated answer to show efficiency. Given the small sample, it's fair to say you were correct :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution which is very similar to @anky_91's one:

```
In [96]: df.col_A.str.replace(r"\s*,\s*", ",").str.get_dummies(",").sum()
Out[96]:
angry        2
happy        4
not happy    1
sad          3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `melt` or `stack` with `str.split` and `value_counts`:

```
df['col_A'].str.split(r',\s?', expand=True).melt()['value'].value_counts()
```

or

```
df['col_A'].str.split(r',\s?', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
happy        4
sad          3
angry        2
not happy    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`series.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and then `str.strip()` the columns and do a `groupby(axis=1).sum().sum()`:

```
m=df.col_A.str.get_dummies(',')
m.groupby(m.columns.str.strip(),axis=1).sum().sum()
```

---

```
angry        2
happy        4
not happy    1
sad          3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df.col_A.str.replace(r"\s*,\s*", ",").str.get_dummies(",").sum()` ?

Comment: @MaxU, that is better. Unfortunately I am off my system now :(. If you want you can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
word_list= df.col_A.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts([i.strip() for i in [x.split(",")]])).sum(axis=0)
```

See if it works

Comment: Thanks @tawab_shakeel. I edited it. Maybe it works now

Answer (score 0):

Whitespaces were getting in the way:

```
In [147]: word_list = df.col_A.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.replace(" ","").split(","))).sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending 
     ...: = False)                                                                                                              

In [148]: word_list                                                                                                             
Out[148]: 
happy       4.0
sad         3.0
angry       2.0
nothappy    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

a step by step solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col_A":["happy, not happy","sad,happy","sad, happy","angry, happy","angry, sad"]})

word_list= df.col_A.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(","))).sum(axis=0)

df = pd.DataFrame(word_list,columns=['count']).reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"words"})

df['words'] = df['words'].str.strip()

df = df.groupby(['words']).sum().sort_values(by=['count'],ascending=[False]).reset_index()
```

```
    words      count
0   happy       4.0
1   sad         3.0
2   angry       2.0
3   not happy   1.0
```